# when i sync my project then tell me (Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices') but i have google-services.json added

Tags: android, google-play-services

**Error**

> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the
>   google-services plugin (information about the latest version is
>   available at
>   https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/)
>   or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.4.2.

**Code**

```
dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
        compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'

    }


    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
```

While the other libraries are a different version:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
```

The version of the gsm/firebase libraries have to match, otherwise you get that error.

WHich you change is up to you, but all the versions have to match. If you change the firebase-core implementation line to:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
```

It will work. Note that this is a universal answer; Any of the firebase or GSM libraries have to match in version. It's irrelevant what dependency, it applies to all

Comment: Thank you sir . for solving my problem.

Comment: need both ? 
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'

Comment: From the looks of things you don't need the `implementation` one. (Not very familiar with Firebase, so I could be wrong)

Comment: i removed 'implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'

Comment: but when i build generate  signed apk  then tell me Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexWithDexForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp$zzc;

Comment: Do you have multiple modules in the project?

Comment: no . i dont have multiple modules

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding the project

Comment: solved. thank you sir

Comment: my apps going unfortunately stop